# Cannot search for a single letter being between A-G in a if statement in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

```
    Dim lastname As String
    Dim pos As Integer


    pos = InStr(txtName.Text, " ")
    lastname = txtName.Text(pos)

    If lastname = [A - D] Then
```

The problem is comparing the lastname initial to the range and I am still a bit fuzzy on it as I had searched for a few sites before coming here and they included the if statement I had.  The error that is occuring is character is not valid

Comment: Could it be that the If statement was `If lastname Like "[A-D]" Then`? [Documentation for the Like operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator).

Answer (score 0):

```vb
If txtName.Text.Contains(" ") AndAlso
    Enumerable.Range(65, 4).Select(Function(i) Chr(i)).Contains(txtName.Text.Split(" "c).Last()(0)) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Yes")
End If
```

The `65, 4` in Enumerable.Range correspond to 65: A, 4: qty of letters to include. According to your code this includes A, B, C, D. According to your question title, you want A through G so it would be `65, 7`.

See http://www.asciitable.com/

If you need a lastName variable, it's pretty similar

```vb
If txtName.Text.Contains(" ") Then
    Dim lastName = txtName.Text.Split(" "c).Last()
    If Enumerable.Range(65, 4).Select(Function(i) Chr(i)).Contains(lastName(0)) Then
        MessageBox.Show("yes")
    End If
End If
```

It uses the Last() function on the split string so these examples will work

- Mr. Bob
- Mr. Joe Bob
- Joe Bob

While these will not work

- JoeBob
- Joe Bob Jr.
- Bob

I just thought of a third! It might make more sense to compare the letter's ascii char code vs. the numbers 65 thru 68 as only one char is being converted to an integer, vs 4 integers being converted to chars.

```vb
If txtName.Text.Contains(" ") Then
    Dim lastName = txtName.Text.Split(" "c).Last()
    If Enumerable.Range(65, 4).Contains(Asc(lastName(0))) Then
        MessageBox.Show("yeS")
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Comments and explanations in line.

```
Private Sub OpCode()
    'Find the position of the first space in the text box
    Dim pos = TextBox2.Text.IndexOf(" ")
    'Get the letter following the space
    Dim Initial = TextBox2.Text(pos + 1)
    'Check if the letter is in the range A-D
    If Initial Like "[A-D]" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Yes")
    End If
End Sub
```